Azure Storage Account IP Address Exception Stopped Working over VPN
New to Azure here and going through some training.  When I set up the training environment in Azure, I was connected through my corporate VPN (not Azure VPN) and set up a storage account.  I'm not making use of an Azure Vnet in my current setup.  I configured the storage account "Public network access" setting to "Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses" and selected the option "Add your client IP address."  Let's call that IP address 23.111.111.111 (not actual IP).  I then set up a container (Private access level) and added some files. I then continued going through some basic training exercises, having no issues accessing data throughout.
I stepped away for a few hours and ended up losing network connectivity on my laptop.  I rebooted the laptop and reconnected to my corporate VPN.  At that point, I could no longer access the container in the storage account (i.e., attempting to open the container via the Azure portal Data Storage > Containers).  Error: This request is not authorized to perform this operation.  This storage account's 'Firewalls and virtual networks' settings may be blocking access to storage services.
I also attempt access through Azure Storage Explorer. Same issue.
I confirmed via several methods that I still had the same public IP address over the VPN (e.g., https://ipinfo.io/ip).  I also went back into the networking settings and removed, saved, readded, and saved my client IP address to the exception list.  Still no change.
If I disconnect from the VPN and add the non-VPN public IP address to the exception list (let's call that IP address 174.222.222.222), I can access the container without issue.
If I change the network setting to "Enabled from all networks," I can connect to the container while connected to the corporate VPN.
However, no matter what I've tinkered with so far, I cannot for the life of me get the container access working again while connected to the VPN with "Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses" configured.
Given that it was absolutely working previously and now refuses to allow access while on the VPN unless I select "Enabled from all networks," what am I missing?  Is this something where I'm going to need to set up a vnet/private endpoint configuration?  I was trying to keep this as simple as possible, and it's definitely not a deal breaker for the training I'm doing, but I'm finding it frustrating, and now I'm on a mission. ;)
My expectation is to be able to connect to the storage account over VPN without enabling access from all networks.
Thanks in advance!

You can check the range of your corporate VPN IP that is used for internet and add the same range to the storage  firewall section.

Disconnect the VPN and connect back and check the public IP of your corporate VPN and add the same IP.

Yup, tried both of these and still no go.

You can check the storage accounts' logs,there it will display the public IP

On the safe side, add the total range of your corporate VPN IP address.normally. once you disconnect and connect to vpn,the IP will change automatically.

I'll spend some time trying to figure out the log features today, but I guess I'm confused as to why my IP address would be something other than the IP address that the Azure portal is recognizing (i.e., the IP address shown for "Add your client IP address ('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx')") under the firewall exception section.  Even if it changed, the next time I log in to the portal, wouldn't it reflect a different IP address there?  This is the same IP address that shows up if I check any publicly available "check your internet IP" service.

Ha!  That is definitely the issue.  Thanks to ChatGPT for getting me the right query to run as I feel like I could spend a whole year trying to figure out this logging interface.  :D   The IP address being logged is from a range I'm not familiar with, so that'll take a little research, but at least I'm headed down the right path.  Thanks @VenkatV!

For future reference, this is the query I ran...
StorageBlobLogs
| where AuthenticationType == "OAuth" or AuthenticationType == "SharedKey"
| project TimeGenerated, AuthenticationType, AccountName, CallerIpAddress


Azure Storage Account IP Address Exception Stopped Working over VPN

Posting our discussion as an answer for the community benefit.
The issue was caused by a change in the public IP address assigned to the corporate VPN connection after reconnecting. While you initially added your client IP address to the firewall exceptions, the IP assigned to you by the corporate VPN likely changed after reconnecting.
Corporate VPNs use dynamic IP addresses from a pool, so your actual public IP could change after reconnecting. If the public IP appears to be the same after reconnecting, you may want to check the storage logs to see which IP is being used for inbound traffic to the storage account
Here is the query to check the access logs for your storage account.
StorageBlobLogs
| where AuthenticationType == "OAuth" or AuthenticationType == "SharedKey"
| project TimeGenerated, AuthenticationType, AccountName, CallerIpAddress

This query will show you the caller IP address, which is the IP address from request originated. You will see the public IP addresses that were used in the request.
If the CallerIpAddress in the logs shows that the IP address assigned by the VPN is different from the one you initially added, add the IP address range that matches the one shown in the storage logs, or add the single IP address.
